# How to specifically set a value in a dictionary as an element on python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I am trying to find a way to understand how to choose a value in a dictionary and set this as an element.

For example:

```
Countries = {'Africa':['Morocco', 'Algeria', 'Egypt'], 'Europe':['Uk', 'France', 'Germany']}
```

How would I set,

```
a = Germany
```

without knowing germany is in the dictionary?

I have tried setting 'a' as a list and then trying to append part of Countries into 'a'.

```
a = Countries['Europe' : -1]
```

However this comes up with 'TypeError unhashable type: 'slice'

Any help would be lovely.

Comment: `a = Countries['Europe'][-1]`.  That will set `a` to the last item in the Europe list (whatever it happens to be).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
a = Countries['Europe'][-1]
```

This accesses all european countries:

```
europe = Countries['Europe']
```

and this is the last european country:

```
last_europe = europe[-1]
```

so combined:

```
a = Countries['Europe'][-1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!